# Permission issue while reading the provider(i.e.Google,Facebook,Firebase) originally used to authenticate user to Firebase 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using Firebase 3.0 and Swift v2.2. I ran into an issue when using Firebase's ***sendPasswordResetWithEmail***  to allow users to reset their passwords in my iOS app. The issue is that the password reset email gets sent to all users even those users that did not originally sign in with Firebase  but instead used the Google sign in button or Facebook sign in button also available in my app. Unfortunately, even if the user gets the email and follows the instructions to reset their password the link provided in the password reset email only resets the password for those accounts that signed in with Firebase; it does not reset their Google or Facebook password. Thus, they still won't be able to sign in.

My solution was to implement the function ***getAuthProvider()*** (shown in the code I provided below) to first get the provider which I am saving in my *user* node in the real time database (as shown below) and depending on the provider I then send the password reset request or show the user an error message stating that they must reset their password with the appropriate provider.

However, the ***queryEqualToValue*** call is returning the error **Permission Denied**. I updated the rules in my Firebase real time database (as shown below). Note, since user's resetting their passwords are non-authenticated users at the time that they request to have their password reset I would like to give them as little access as possible. I do not want to allow them to access user's first name and last name, I would prefer to only give them access to read the provider. What am I missing? Thanks for any input!

**Firebase hierarchy:**

- user

  - uid

    - email
    - firstname
    - lastname
    - provider [values: "Firebase" or "Google.com" or "Facebook.com"]

**Firebase rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "user": {
      "uid": {
        "$provider": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ViewController code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ResetPasswordTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Hide navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

        //Text fields delegates
        self.emailTextField.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Hide status bar
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func resetPasswordButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject?) {

        //Set user fields
        let email = emailTextField.text

        // Check for empty fields
        if (email!.isEmpty)
        {
            // Display error message
            displayAlertMessage(REQUIRED_FIELDS_ERROR_TITTLE, message: REQUIRED_FIELDS_ERROR_MESSAGE)

            return;
        }

        // Validate email address
        if !(UserAccountValidator.validateEmailTextField(email!)) { //if invalid email format
            // Display error message
            self.displayAlertMessage(REENTER_EMAIL_ERROR_TITLE, message: REENTER_EMAIL_ERROR_TITLE)
            return
        }

        // Get the current user's provider, only those users who were authenticated with Firebase as the provider should be sent a reset password email
        let authProvider = getAuthProvider(email!)
        if (!authProvider.isEmpty && authProvider == "Firebase") {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(email!) { error in
                // Back to main thread
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                    if  error != nil {
                        if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code) {
                            switch (errorCode) {
                            case .ErrorCodeUserNotFound:
                                self.displayAlertMessage(EMAIL_NOTFOUND_3RDPARTY_ERROR_TITLE, message: EMAIL_NOTFOUND_3RDPARTY_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                return
                            default:
                                self.displayAlertMessage(ACCOUNT_CREATION_DB_ERROR_TITLE, message: ACCOUNT_CREATION_DB_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                return
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Present reset password success view
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("resetPasswordSuccessView", sender: self)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Display error message
            displayAlertMessage("Authentication Provider Mismatch", message: "It looks like you originally signed in with this email using Google or Facebook. Please reset your password with the appropriate provider and then come back and sign in with your new password.")
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Local Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    func getAuthProvider(email: String) -> String {
        //Retrieve Authentication Provider for a given UID
        var authProvider: String = ""
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user").queryEqualToValue(email).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            authProvider = snapshot.value!["provider"] as! String
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return authProvider
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Display Error Message Methods
    //--------------------------------------
    func displayAlertMessage(title:String,message:String)
    {
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler:nil);

        alertMessage.addAction(okAction);

        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I reduce your question, this code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user").queryEqualToValue(email).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
```

Fails to read for an unauthenticated user with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "user": {
      "uid": {
        "$provider": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Two things:

1. the `uid` in your rules is a literal string. To make the rules under it apply to every child-node of `user` the name should start with a `$`, e.g. `$uid` or `$email` (the actual name doesn't matter: if it starts with a $ it is a wildcard/variable).
2. you have `uid` in your rules, but are passing in a variable named `email`. I'm not sure if those ever match, but it sounds odd.
3. you are trying to read a specific user (`/user/<myuid>`), but are only granting public read access to `$provider` (`/user/<myuid>/<provider>`). The read will fail, since you don't grant access. See [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the Firebase documentation.